# Convert "Sentence case" to "camelCase" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

Having a difficult time finding a solution to this, there are several solutions for the reverse.

I have considered replacing every " " and the following first character with an uppercase version of itself:

```
value.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, function (g) { return g[1].toUpperCase() })
```

Only, the regex **/\s+/g** needs to be changed to match  the first character.

If there is an existing question that is exactly this, provide link and I will close this myself. I can't find a solution on SO

---

Examples:

"I walk my dog to the park" or "i Walk my DOG to the Park" => "iWalkMyDogToThePark"

Comment: Can you provide a complete example of the intended result?

Comment: An example would be better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to catch the next character. You can use (.) or ([a-z])

```
var toCamelCase = function(string){
  return string.replace(/\s+(.)/g, function (match, group) { 
    return group.toUpperCase()  
  })
}
```

Comment: Nice, that's what I was looking for and @lpg has the same solution, I'll upvote. I didn't want to have an unnecessary conditional, thanks for this regex change.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you could use this:

```
function camelCase(value) { 
    return value.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+(.)/g, function(match, group1) {
        return group1.toUpperCase();
    });
}
```

(taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425287/convert-string-to-camelcase-with-regular-expression))

Answer (score 1):

You can use this camel case conversion code:

```
function toCamelCase(str) {
  return str.replace(/(?:^.|[A-Z]|\b.)/g, function(letter, index) {
    return index == 0 ? letter.toLowerCase() : letter.toUpperCase();
  }).replace(/\s+/g, '');
}

var val = toCamelCase("Sentence case");
//=> sentenceCase

val = toCamelCase('hello how are you');
//=> helloHowAreYou
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
var string = "Hello there what are You doing yes";
string.replace(/([A-Z])([a-z]+)\s+([a-z])([a-z]+)/g, function($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) { 
    return $2.toLowerCase() + $3 + $4.toUpperCase() + $5; 
});
```

This prints out `"helloThere what are youDoing yes"`.

Answer (score 0):

I think a simpler solution can be achieved without Regex. Just split the string from spaces, and join them with the appropriate casing.

```
var value = '...';

var camelCase = value.split(' ').map(function(word, i) {
    return (word[0] || '')[i == 0 ? 'toLowerCase' : 'toUpperCase']() +
           word.substr(1).toLowerCase();
}).join('');
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aYAaJ/2/)**

Comment: And you will get the error `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined"` if there happens to be double spaces. [I know it is not in the test case above]

Comment: Why replace and not just split on one or more spaces? `.split(/\s+/)`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the following (ES6):

```
function camelCase (str) {
    return str.split(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g).map((x, index) => {
        if (index === 0) return x.toLowerCase()
        return x.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + x.substr(1).toLowerCase()
    }).join('')
}
```

It takes the assumption that in general, the aim to convert to camelCase is for variables, so no accents or odd chars should be present (or will be split).

```
camelCase("I walk my dog to the park")
> "iWalkMyDogToThePark"
```