# Regex to Remove Special characters and Spaces and Then Camel Case It

Tags: regex

I am trying to generate C# Properties by using regex out of question names. I have more than 100 and task is likely to be repeated so it's worth putting effort into it.

Strings to be converted:

```
Do you own your property?
How is it owned?
Relationship to other registered owner
Estimated value of Estate (joint)
Address Line 1
Are any of the children under 18 years old?
Are you interested in safeguarding your assets for your children/beneficiaries?
```

Expected outcome:

```
public string DoYouOwnYourProperty { get; set;}
public string HowIsItOwned { get; set;}
public string RelationshipToOtherRegisteredOwner { get; set;}
public string EstimatedValueOfEstateJoint { get; set;}
public string AddressLine1 { get; set;}
public string AreAnyOfTheChildrenUnder18YearsOld { get; set;}
public string AreYouInterestedInSafeguardingYourAssetsForYourChildrenBeneficiaries { get; set;}
```

I was snooping around and found flavours of regex questions where [they would remove special chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374822/javascript-regexp-remove-all-special-characters) or [would UpperCase it in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425287/convert-string-to-camelcase-with-regular-expression) but not do both with regex only.

I [started out with this](http://regex101.com/r/aJ1aC3/2)

```
([a-zA-z])( [a-zA-z])([a-zA-z])
```

Replace:

```
\1\U2\3
```

However group 2 does not get upper-cased, and I am not sure how to append `public string` and `{ get; set;}` for everything and not per group.

Comment: Uppercasing isn't a "standard" regex operation, it depends on the tool. What are you using?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski for developing regex i use 101regex, and for replace i intend to use notepad++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Notepad++:

**Step 1:** Remove punctuation

Replace the following pattern:

```
[^\w\s]
```

With an empty string.

**Step 2:** Remove spaces and make letters uppercase

Replace the following pattern:

```
[^\S\r\n]+(\d*\p{L}|\d+)
```

With this:

```
\U$1
```

**Step 3:** Add the property syntax

Replace the following pattern:

```
^(\S+)$
```

With this:

```
public string $1 { get; set; }
```

---

For reference, here's what Notepad++ uses for regex replacements: [Boost-Extended Format String Syntax](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/boost_format_syntax.html)

Comment: Hi again, it does fail with way to many cases, numbers in properties would be one of them. `Recipient Surname
Recipient Title
Address Line 1
Address Line 2
Address Line 3
Address Line 4
Address Line 5
Address Line 6
Post Code
`

Comment: Oops, I didn't think about numbers. I've corrdcted the patterns, they should work

Comment: Blew up on single case `Estimated value of Estate (joint)` worked with 100+. Still one case can be done by hand, thanks mate.

Comment: I inverted the two first steps, so it should work for your last case now

Answer (score 2):

You can't work with *[regex101.com](http://regex101.com)* as Its accessible engines don't support `\U` and `\L` replacement tokens. However Notepad++ is okay.

**At first**, use this regex to match those spaces/punctuation and their following character:

```
[^[:alnum:]\n\r](\w)?
```

replace it with

```
\U$1
```

[image]
**Second**, match the recent whole line:

```
^(?i)([a-z\d]+)$
```

and replace with:

```
public string $1 { get; set;}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, didn't handle cases with numbers. `Executor Title
Address Line 1
Address Line 2
Address Line 3
Address Line 4
Address Line 5
Address Line 6
Post Code
Home Phone Number
Mobile Number
Email
Notes to solicitor
Are any of the children under 18 years old?
Do you have executor(s)?`

Comment: After update `[^[:alnum:]\n\r]\d*(\w)?` removes numbers that produces 6 x AddressLine without number at the end (Address Line 1 and Address Line 2 are two distinct properties)

Comment: @LIUFA I rolled back first regex, modified second one. Check update.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you very much. I have accepted other answer as @Lucas was first but I have gave you same amount of rep by + your other answers.